# Regular Expression for a code that starts with specific letters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How can I build a regular expression that will check this code:

> ABC00000

The `ABC` is fixed and the `0` is a place holder for numbers.

The maximum length of numbers is 5.

Comment: Downvote reason: SO is not a "write my code for me" kind of website. you should show your efforts.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fW7qG4/1

Comment: Tip : You can do it in a easier way without using Regex.

Comment: thanks guys .. i have already tried the suggested code. but it was showing me an error on http://regexr.com/ that's why i was looking for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Regex:

```
ABC(\d{5})
```

The capturing group will also help you to retrieve the number after 'ABC', if you need it.

A non-regex way:

```
testString = "ABC00000";

if (testString.StartsWith("ABC") && int.TryParse(testString.Substring(3), 0))
{

}
```

The above code basically checks if the first three characters are 'ABC' and the last 5 characters are numeric. The `int.TryParse()` function returns if the number is parse-able from the string, i.e., if it is a number.

Comment: thanks! that really helped

Comment: You should check for the string length just in case

Comment: @Widi The OP says that 'ABC' is fixed and the maximum number of digits will be 5.